# How to make left justify in table

Tags: tables

How to make left justify in table?

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    0               && 0 \\
    3x + y                          && 7\\
    3x                          && -675+867i\\
    x                 && \\
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I do not know why does not work?

Comment: The table building environments are `tabular` and `array`. Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve?

Comment: It is good to start from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In LaTeX terminology, a `table` is a "floating environment", meaning that it may get typeset not exactly where it's encountered in the input file but somewhere else (usually not too far away though) in order to obtain a decent page layout. The *main content* of a `table` environment -- other content being, for instance, the table's caption, legend, and table-related footnotes -- is usually placed inside a `tabular` environment (if the tabular material is mostly text) or an `array` environment (if the material is mostly math).

Left-alignment of the contents of a column is achieved by using the `l` column type, specified as an argument to `\begin{tabular}` or `\begin{array}`. To change the distance between columns, modify either `\tabcolsep` (for `tabular` environments) or `\arraycolsep` (for `array` environments).

In the case of your example, I would suggest you use an `array` environment, as it contains all mathy stuff.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
%\centering %% uncomment this if the "array" should be centered
\setlength\arraycolsep{10pt} % default value: 5pt
$\begin{array}{ll}           % "ll" sets up two left-aligned columns
    0               & 0 \\
    3x + y          & 7 \\
    3x              & -675+867i\\
    x               & \\
\end{array}$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the parameter following the `\begin{array}` defines the number and alignment of columns.

Comment: @JosephMontanaro - thanks for this; I'll add a comment to the code

Comment: Also, if you don't want it to float, just remove the table environment, and just keep the array.

Answer (score 10):

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\end{tabular}
```

`ccc` show 3 columns and center positionings. You can use `lll` or `rrr` for left and right  positioning

Comment: The question was explicitly about how to get left-justified columns. Your code should address the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull your whole table more to the left by using `@{}` in the definition of the columns:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc} 
;;;
\end{tabular}
```